# How to set index of a MySql table using WHERE, RANGE and SORT?

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I have MySql table and query that I'm trying to optimize and have some questions.

```
SELECT value FROM table WHERE userid=?userid AND date <= ?date AND deleted='False' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
    `tableid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `userid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `value` double DEFAULT '0',
    `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
    `deleted` enum('False','True') DEFAULT 'False',
    PRIMARY KEY (`tableid`),
    KEY `userid_date` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I get the following EXPLAIN result for the query:

```
id    select_type    table       type    possible_keys    key            key_len    ref    rows    Extra
1     SIMPLE         table       ref     userid_date      userid_date   5          const  4       Using where; Using filesort
```

If I change to use also date in the userid_date key (KEY `userid_date` (`userid`,`date`)) I get the following EXPLAIN result:

```
id    select_type    table    type    possible_keys    key            key_len    ref    rows    Extra
1     SIMPLE         table    range   userid_date      userid_date  9          NULL   4       Using where
```

This is better as it is not using filesort, but it seems like the type is not as good as when only using userid as key. How would you set the index for a table and query like this? Is it good to use a date type as index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is better as it is not using filesort

yes, and because one more where filter is available in the index.

You could also think about adding deleted `(userid, deleted, date)`. However, make sure that the equal comparison go before the column you use for the range and order by clause--otherwise your sort will come back.

> but it seems like the type is not as good as when only using userid

why? I think your index will be good enough. the `deleted` column might not be worth, and maybe just wasting space. but that depends if other queries use the column as well and how the 'False' rate is in you database.